# How to implement Haskell equivalent of invokeAll

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm looking for equivalent functionality to [ExecutorService.invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in Haskell. Do I need to implement it? From documentation:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete.

In my use case, tasks spend most of their time waiting on IO, so I only need to avoid constantly blocking main thread which would build up a collection of `Either` results or errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard solution to that category of problems is the ["async"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) library. As much as I understand your problem you need something like this:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

processActions :: [IO a] -> IO ()
processActions actions = do
  -- Execute all the actions concurrently and
  -- get a list of asyncs (an equivalent to futures):
  asyncs <- mapM async actions
  -- Do whatever you want...
  -- ...
  -- Block until all the asyncs complete:
  mapM_ wait asyncs
```

However the library provides a lot of other patterns, so you should just check it out. There's a possibility that what you need is the [`mapConcurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.1.5/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v%3amapConcurrently) function.

Answer (score 2):

No problems.  Just use the [`async`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.1.5/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) library and run `mapM async someListOfJobs` to get a list of `Async`s on which you can `wait`, `poll`, and many other operations.

Comment: `mapM async` would be the better option, since it would instead return `IO [Async a]` instead of `[IO (Async a)]`.

Comment: @bheklilr  Indeed, that was my intent.  Edited.